# When a particle cannot move according to following rules, it is located at point $(r, r)$. What is $r$?

Tags: combinatorics, logic

> For any $a$ and $b$, we will define a "move that adds $(a, b)$" as a
>   move from any point $(c, d)$ to the point $(c+a, d+b)$. A particle
>   moves according to the following rules. If a move added $(p, q)$ to
>   get to the current position, then the next move will add either $(p-1, q)$ or $(p, q-1)$ to move to the next position. Neither $p$ nor $q$
>   can ever be negative. Suppose particle $A$ moves to $(3, 4)$ from the
>   origin according to the preceding rules, and will continue moving
>   according to the preceding rules. When particle $A$ can no longer
>   move, it is located at point $(r, r)$. What is the value of $r$ for
>   particle $A$?

I begin this problem by looking at the rules mentioned. I can reason that the move that added $(a, b)$ was $a=3$, $b=4$. So thus, the next move will either add $(2, 4)$, or $(3, 3)$, and so on, with the end result being the same no matter what. So, I decide that I can add up one sequence that works, and it will lead to the correct answer (which is $\boxed{14}$ BTW).

I start with $(3, 4)$. A next move can add $(2, 4)$... and I go down the line. Here is the addition sequence I created: $$(3, 4)$$ $$(2, 4)$$$$(1, 4)$$$$(0, 4)$$$$(0, 3)$$$$(0, 2)$$$$(0, 1)$$$$(0, 0)$$ When I add them up, I, however, get $(6, 22)$, which is clearly not in the form $(r, r)$. What is wrong with my reasoning? How can I solve this?

Furthermore, I figured(just for experiment) to add $6$ and $22$ together, and take their average, which happens to be $14$, and the correct answer. Is this a coincidence?

Comment: You are *assuming* that it lands on some spot $(r,r)$. This should be possible with a different sequence of moves.

Comment: No, it's not a coincidence. Rather, you want to total amount of $x$ and $y$ increase to be equal. As such, realize that the sum of the total changes of $x$ and $y$ is constant regardless of what moves you make. What does that tell you...

Comment: The end result  (the final coordinate) strongly depends on the decision which of $p,q$ is decremented at every step. Just try to do this other way around.

Comment: @DonThousand so you mean that I need to add a sequence with the intention to let $x$ and $y$ in the end equal?

Comment: I don't think that Don Thousand had this in mind. The subtle point here is exactly the possibility to end up at a point $(r,r)$. If you however accept this as given, finding $r$ is simple as any possible endpoint $(x,y)$ satisfies $x+y=28$.

Comment: @user Oh! I see what you mean! Mind writing an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that since at every step one of $a,b $ is decremented by 1 their sum is also decremented by 1, decreasing from $7$ to $0$.

The end position of the particle is the sum over $(a_n,b_n) $:
$$(x,y)=\sum_{n\ge0\atop (a_n,b_n)\ne(0,0)}(a_n,b_n) $$
with $(a_0,b_0) =(3,4)$.
This implies:
$$
x+y=\sum_{n\ge0\atop (a_n,b_n)\ne(0,0)}a_n+b_n=\sum_{n\ge0\atop a_0+b_0-n>0}(a_0+b_0-n)=\sum_{n=0}^6 7-n=28.$$

Since the actual end position of the point is $(r,r) $ we have 
$$2r=28\implies r=14.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For coordinate $(x, y)$ it will be that $x+y=28$ and I want to find a coordinate where $x=y$ which is $x=y=\frac{28}{2}=\boxed{14}$.